# snap object bounding box corner to group bounding box corner

Tags: inkscape, snapping

I am using Inkscape 0.92.

I open a PDF using poppler/cairo import. Then I get a group with a bounding box like this:

[image]

Now I import an image which also has a bounding box:

[image]

I'd like to snap a corner of the image bounding box to a corner of the group bounding box, but it does not work.

**What do I need to do to get it working?**

I tried snapping two objects (i.e. I imported another image); this works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using the 'Object → Align and Distribute...' panel.

Select your group, then your other object. Set the 'Relative to' drop-down to something so that it's relative to the group. This could be 'First selected' or 'Last selected' depending on the order you selected them in the first step, or you could probably use 'Biggest object' since your group is bigger in this case.

Finally use the 'Align left edges' and 'Align bottom edges' buttons.

[image: Align and Distribute demo]

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be resolved if you group your objects with a rectangle to make a physical box. The rectangle can be white, or it can be totally invisible with no stroke and no fill.

Snapping doesn't work on a group bounding box if there is no object to snap to inside the group.  Or rather I should say bounding box snapping only works on objects.

Here's the example - the rectangles here are filled so you can see them.

[image]

After removing the fill and stroke of the rectangles, snapping still works

[image]

Comment: The +1 is for the info "Snapping doesn't work on a group bounding box if there is no object to snap to inside the group. Or rather I should say bounding box snapping only works on objects.".